# What is the correct pronunciation of “regex”?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, computing, portmanteau-words

The term *regular expression* is often shortened to *regex*. What is the correct pronunciation of the *g* in *regex*?

Is it like the *g*<sup>1</sup>  in *gallium*, or is it like the *g*<sup>2</sup>  in *giraffe*? I’ve heard it said both ways.

---

<sub>1.   IPA /g/ 

2.  IPA /dʒ/</sub>

Comment: Since it's /ɡ/ in _regular_, it's /ɡ/ when it shortens to _regex_. Changes like this take place in **speech**, not spelling. Spelling rules do not affect speech; rather, speech affects spelling rules. Occasionally.

Comment: As in all cases where a portmanteau is formed from two words, the pronunciation is preserved in the portmanteau -- the sounds are identical in the original words and the new one.

Comment: @JohnLawler Second thoughts: Could there be exceptions to what I stated just now in the above comment of mine?

Comment: There can always be local variants; if somebody in a company decides it's cool to pronounce it /'rɛdʒɛks/, it might catch on there. But that's close to being a pun with _rejects_, so you want to make sure the stressed vowel is mid lax instead of high tense.

Comment: The post coleopterist linked to seems to indicate that there isn't one correct answer to this. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kris: in my experience, portmanteau words regularly change the pronunciation of the individual parts. Certainly, [when my boss pronounced *favicon* according to your rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/how-to-pronounce-favicon), our web designer didn't have a clue what he was talking about.

Comment: @coleopterist, I think that is, indeed, a duplicate; but I think this is a nice illustration of why it's actually good to have duplicates, because this question's title is much more likely to match what someone is searching for than the older question's title.

Comment: I wonder if there's a regexp to detect duplicate questions. [Pp]ortmanteau+

Comment: @rajah9 English would need to be a  [Chomsky Type-3 grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) for that to be possible ;)

Comment: English ain't no Type-3 Regular language ;-)

Comment: It's pronounced Ray-hacks, of course!  What?

Comment: @Kris: Interesting question. The only possible exception I could think of was Wikipedia; I usually hear the _i's_ in "Wiki" pronounced like "kiwi", but I often hear the second vowel of "Wikipedia" pronounced with more of a schwa (ə) sound. But I don't know if that example would even count, because (1) it's just a subtle vowel shift, and (2) it's a [controversial pronunciation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeCuQk1fa9w) as well.

Comment: @Cthulhu: yes, there isn't one correct answer. I disagree with John Lawler: I pronounce it /'rɛdʒɛks/, and I think most of my friends and colleagues do too.

Comment: @Marthaª As you must have learnt from the accepted answer there by now, you boss was *right* and your design person was not equipped enough to understand it. /fav-ee-can/ ? ah, yes, must be teen-slang. That reference question helps to know what disasters can happen when pronunciation changes in a portmanteau word.

Comment: @Marthaª I thought you said "but I think this is a nice illustration of why it's actually good to have duplicates," then why vote to close, and be the first at it? :)

Comment: @Kris: because it's still a duplicate, of course. It should be kept around as a signpost to the original question, but there's really no need for it to sit around collecting more answers.

Comment: I pronounce it /rɪ'gɛks/. Sounds cooler and easier to roll the tongue

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On page 27 of [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/), [Jeffrey Friedl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Friedl) states:

> Instead, I normally use "regex." It just rolls right off the tongue ("it rhymes with "FedEx," with a **hard *g* sound like "regular"** and **not a soft one** like in "Regina") and it is amenable to a variety of uses like "when you regex ...," "budding regexers," and even "regexification."

So, if you are looking for an authoritative answer, the above is it.

In a footnote, Friedl also adds:

> You might also come across the decidedly unsightly "regexp." I'm not sure how one would pronounce that, but those with a lisp might find it a bit easier.

---

FWIW, *I* pronounce it with the *soft g* simply because it sounds better to mine ears. However, most of the programmers I know do employ the *hard g*.

Comment: I say *rejex*, rejecting the hard *g* in favor of a more mellifluous phoneme. But I also say *gif* (not *jif*) for `.gif` files.

Comment: @Robusto I've always said *rejex*. Must un-learn that now. :(
And *jif* somehow sounds better does it not?

Comment: @Robusto -- Steve Wilhite, who invented the graphics format, said the name should pronounces "like the [peanut butter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jif_%28peanut_butter%29)".  There's no such authority (to my knowledge) for the pattern language, so, like you, I'm going with majority rules.

Comment: @Cthulhu: I do not plan to unlearn that. I don't care how Jeffrey Friedl or anyone else may pronounce it. Nobody has failed to understand what I meant so far, except those who don't know what regex is.

Comment: @Malvolio: I don't care what Steve Wilhite says, either.

Comment: @Cthulhu I pronounce it the same way for the same reasons that Robusto outlined. However, most of the people I know do use the hard _g_.

Comment: @Robusto- Bravo. I have been saying *rejex* for the past 25 years as well and don't plan on changing.

Comment: @Jim -- do you generally make this plans ahead of time?

Comment: @Malvolio- Well, you certainly can't make plans after the fact.

Comment: Hm, does one use a hard or a soft *g* when pluralizing *rex* into *reges*? :)

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that *any* pronunciation of "regex" would rhyme with "FedEx." Seems kind of sloppy wording in the original quote...

Comment: Friedl is trolling for sure. Only a monster would pronounce it that way.

Comment: An _accepted_ answer using "it sounds better to _mine_ ears"? Well, that's odd. Is it so only because it's SO? :-)

Comment: The right answer is reJex and Jif. Nothing to talk about

Answer (score 20):

Sweet reason clearly dictates, as an abbreviation of *regular*, it should be pronounced /ɹɛ.ɡɛks/.  However, I've heard it said thousands of times and far more often than not, it is pronounced /ɹɛ.dʒɛks/.  Dunno why, but there it is.

Comment: Reason has nothing to do with how a word is pronounced in practice. :-)

Answer (score 9):

It matters how you link the word to Regular Expression.

1) RegEx => /ɹɛɡ.ɛks/ => You're new to Regular Expression - the word. You're capturing it with two words Reg and Ex.

2) regex => /ɹɛdʒɛks/ => You're very familiar with the word Regular Expression - your mind doesn't remember the full word when you say `regex`. You think it a whole word to Regular Expression.

So, if you're pronouncing it with the hard g sound, then your mind still captures the full word. And if you're pronouncing it with soft g sound, then your mind doesn't capture the full word but you just capture the word `regex` as full word.

Answer (score 4):

I've always heard rejeks or even reejeks. Never heard any other pronunciation. It doesn't lend itself very well to extending. I've been regexing is weird. I never say "regex" to the uninitiated or even "regular expression". Stick instead with word or character pattern.

Comment: Just call it a *pattern*.